# How to include the property file when building android project using Facebook Buck

Tags: android, facebook, maven, ant, intellij-idea

I'm using Facebook Buck to build my android project. Currently, I have a property file (like local.properties) in android src directory. And I would read this file in my java file. When I successfully built the project and run the apk, the application cannot find the property file. How can I write the BUCK file and make the property file included.

Answer (score 0):

Specify it in the list of `resources` for your `java_library()` or `android_library()`: http://facebook.github.io/buck/rule/java_library.html.

Also, reading resources via `Class.getResource()` can be very slow on Android. You are better off treating the data as an Android resource or asset.